# How do I add something to BaseCamp's events section like github in c#

Tags: basecamp

The github integration with Basecamp adds items to the progress and events section of Basecamp without actually adding a message, calendar, todo, etc. When looking at the api https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api the events are all read-only. I tried doing a post request to /projects/x/events.json but got back a (422) Unprocessable Entity error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems undocumented, but the requirements to post to the events api are as follows:

description, url, title, and service

If you have all those in your json object and post to the events api /projects/x/events.json it will work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the parameters mean / represent (specifically `url` and `service`)?  Also, do the Events you create via the API appear in the "summary" page of a basecamp project?

Comment: @NathanAnderson I don't see any documentation for this, but you can extrapolate what they are used for from the Basecamp Events API documentation's examples: https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/events.md

Comment: Can anyone confirm this still works for the Basecamp2 api? There are no corresponding attributes in the JSON for the ones mentioned here.